# What is the best practise for configuring Web-Handler mappings in IIs 8.5?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

We've moving a legacy application from 2003 to 2012R2.

As part of this we're using a legacy deployment script which deploys the site code, including its web.config file.

In prepping the servers I wrote powershell scripts to set up as much as possible of the previous manual config.  This included new-webhandler calls to add web handlers.

These are over written by the deploy.

What is the best practise for managing the conflict between occasional deployments and ongoing support?

Comment: Its important to understand how Location Tags work in IIS 7+.   You'll want to make sure you are making "Site" or "App" specific configuration for all that carryover:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8

Comment: I like to refer to XKCD's [Is It Worth the Time?](https://xkcd.com/1205/) Automation Chart. When deployments are infrequent, and fix requires a small amount of time, sometimes it outweighs the amount of time to develop the script.  But at he same time, I think that it is important to have a solid deployment script that works. At the very least, modifying the deployment script (or even having a "post" deployment script) would make it easier for you, but also allow others to be able to run the script as well.

Comment: For IIS 8 and above, make sure you use IISAdministration, or WebAdministration, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery. "overwritten by the deploy"? What's that?

Comment: Thanks @LexLi .  WHat I mean is that :
Powershell commands write teh webhandler mappings into the web.config file.
The deployment script pulls the web.config file from the development source location and writes this to the server.  This copy doesn't have the web handlers in them

Comment: If you don't show the deployment script, there is nothing to be discussed.

Comment: Literally all it does in this context is copy the web.config file from a filestore over to the server, over writing the changes made to it on the server.

Maybe I'm not explaining this well - I know exactly what is happening, I'm just asking if people have had this before, and come up with a strategy for how to a) not impede development but also b) not mean you can't make changes via the GUI/Powershell